# Make Button Animation like in Google (Ripple Effect)

Tags: html, css, animation, button

I found a button on a website that has the animation of a google Button.

[image]

How do you make such a button that it makes an animation wherever you click?

Here is my code what I have done so far:

```css
button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.8em;
  width: 100px;
  background: #0053d9;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(80%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.92)
}
```

```html
<button>Login</button>
```

Comment: You will have to use JS as well as CSS to make the "ripple" come out of where the mouse is, but if you want the ripple to come out of the middle of the button, that is possible with pure CSS. Which of these 2 options do you want?

Comment: As @AlphaHowl said, you will need to use Javascript if you want the ripple to come out from where the mouse is. You can refer to this example to create a similar button https://codepen.io/BretCameron/pen/mdPMVaW

Comment: @AlphaHowl To be honest I would like to have the JS version but the CSS version would be nice too

Comment: Ok, hang on....

Comment: @PR7 oh that's cool too! Thanks!

Comment: Since you already have the JS version from the link from @PR7, I presume you'd like the CSS-only one.

Comment: @AlphaHowl yes that's right sir

Comment: On closer inspection, the button in the link is not perfect because the ripple is created when the button is clicked, but Google makes their ripple `onmousedown` - not `onclick`, so I'll just make both versions for completion's sake :)

Comment: @AlphaHowl Ok, thank you so much. You will get the checkmark for this :D

Comment: No problem, and thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is known as the *Material ripple effect* (or at least that's along the lines of what most people call it).

There are two ways to accomplish this effect - one using JS and CSS, for the full-fledged effect, which means the ripple comes out of where the mouse is, and one using pure CSS, and no JS - which results in the ripple coming out of the button no matter where the mouse is inside the button.

Some people prefer the CSS-only one as it is cleaner, but most prefer the full-fledged version as it takes into account the mouse position and hence delivers a slightly better experience...

Anyway, I've created both these effects, chose whichever you prefer :).

PS: here are the rules for any full-fledged versions you see:

- The ripple must be created when the mouse is down on the button - **not** when the mouse is clicked because that takes an extra hundred miliseconds on mobile devices (because mobile browsers delay delivering the click event to be able to check if it is a single click or a double click). So with this kind of dalay before showing the ripple, user experience goes down drastically as your site will seem slow and laggy even though it probably isn't.
- The ripple must stay on the button and cover its background until the mouse is up, or the button has lost focus - whichever comes first.

Without further ado, here is the code...

```js
window.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    const target = e.target;

    if(target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && !target.classList.contains("css-only-ripple")) {
      show_ripple(target);
    }
  });
  function show_ripple(button) {
    const style = getComputedStyle(button);
    let ripple_elmnt = document.createElement("span");
    let diameter = Math.max(parseInt(style.height), parseInt(style.width)) * 1.5;
    let radius = diameter / 2;

    ripple_elmnt.className = "ripple";
    ripple_elmnt.style.height = ripple_elmnt.style.width = diameter + "px";
    ripple_elmnt.style.position = "absolute";
    ripple_elmnt.style.borderRadius = "1000px";
    ripple_elmnt.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    
    ripple_elmnt.style.left = event.clientX - button.offsetLeft - radius + "px";
    ripple_elmnt.style.top = event.clientY - button.offsetTop - radius + "px";

    ripple_elmnt.style.transform = "scale(0)";
    ripple_elmnt.style.transition = "transform 500ms ease, opacity 400ms ease";
    ripple_elmnt.style.background = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
    button.appendChild(ripple_elmnt);

    setTimeout(() => {
      ripple_elmnt.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    }, 10);

    button.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      ripple_elmnt.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        try {
          button.removeChild(ripple_elmnt);
        } catch(er) {}
      }, 400);
    }, {once: true});
    button.addEventListener("blur", e => {
      ripple_elmnt.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        try {
          button.removeChild(ripple_elmnt);
        } catch(er) {}
      }, 450);
    }, {once: true});
  }
```

```css
button {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 0.8em;
      width: 100px;
      background: #0053d9;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 500;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    button:hover {
      filter: brightness(80%);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:active {
      transform: scale(0.92)
    }

    .css-only-ripple::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 150%;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
      pointer-events: none;
      border-radius: 999px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }

    .css-only-ripple:focus::after {
      animation: scale_up 1000ms forwards;
    }

    @keyframes scale_up {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<button>Login</button>
<button class="css-only-ripple">Login</button>

<br>
The first button is the CSS and JS version, and the second is the CSS-only version. For the CSS-only button, you have to unfocus it before you click it again or the ripple will not show (it only gets created on focus)
```

Comment: My pleasure : )